# How to decrement an IPV4 address using java library?

Tags: java, java-8, ipv4

I am converting a nodejs code into Java8.

In node there are code as shown below

```
  var ipToEndAt = ippp.prev("192.168.1.225");
```

result of `ipToEndAt`  is `"192.168.1.224"`

I need to convert this line into a java code. I searched for SubnetUtils library, but couldn't find anything appropriate.

similar i also need to increment ip address by 1

can anyone suggest a library or a code snippet ? which ever would be best

Answer (score 6):

Although it's not overly hard to do it yourself, there's an [InetAddresses](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html) class in Guava that allows this kind of operations. And [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) is a very useful addition to your toolchest anyways.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.225");
address = InetAddresses.decrement(address);
```

See, that looks almost identical to the JS code.

In your comment you state that you are unable to use the decrement method, which indicates that you have a really old version of Guava.

https://github.com/google/guava/commit/d39130651d8a90f5ebe066de7f0b2311806e5152#diff-1207ec0a4b5d3f5e5c2236b7373eefc9

[The project home page](https://github.com/google/guava) contains instructions on how to add the current version (25.1) to your project's dependencies.

Comment: i am unable to use decrement method . suggesting only for increment method

Comment: Can you explain (ideally as an edit to your question) why you are unable to use the decrement method? It will help me and other visitors to better understand your problem and give better suggestions.

Comment: i am using STS editor . When i give InetAddresses.decrement(address); it gives an error asking to change to increment  . also  after typing InetAddresses. i  looked for available methods . here decrement does not shows up ,

Comment: See my edit, you're using a very old version of Guava. Fix that and you will be set.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/), in a manner that is polymorphic between IPv4 and IPv6. Also, it is not limited to incrementing or decrementing by 1 as with Guava, you can use any long value and catch AddressValueException in the case of overflow.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of IPAddress.

Sample code:

```java
IPAddress result = increment("192.168.1.225", -1);
System.out.println(result);

result = increment("::", 1);
System.out.println(result);

static IPAddress increment(String addrStr, long inc) throws AddressValueException {
    return new IPAddressString(addrStr).getAddress().increment(inc);
}
```

Output:

```
192.168.1.224
::1
```

More elaborate [sample code at the IPAddress wiki](https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress/wiki/Code-Examples#iterate-through-subnet-boundaries)